# Extjs 5.0.1: Getting white space in grid while scrolling when we give border-radius to grid or to its any parent

Tags: extjs, extjs5

Problem: Getting white space while scrolling grid.This whitespace goes away when we mouseover on grid.

Steps: Assign border-radius css property to grid through css/style config.

Sample Code:

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
   style:'border-radius:4px;',
});
```

This is **[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2j0u&view/editor)**

Note: this happens in chrome Version **68.0.3440.42** (Official Build) beta (64-bit).

Please suggest if there is any workaround or any fix !!

Also I wanted to ask why we have **transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)** for x-grid-item-container div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve this by using [`overflow: visible;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) property on [`grid`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/api/Ext.grid.Panel.html) style.

You can check this working [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/2j11).

Code snippet:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            style: 'border-radius:4px;overflow: visible;',
            title: 'DEMO',
            store: {
                type: 'datastore',
                autoLoad: true
            },
            columns: [{
                text: 'Name',
                dataIndex: 'name',
                flex: 1
            }, {
                text: 'Email',
                dataIndex: 'email',
                flex: 1
            }, {
                text: 'Phone',
                dataIndex: 'phone',
                flex: 1
            }],
            height: 200,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I wanted to know what is use of transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) for x-grid-item-container div.

Comment: refer this [MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate3d) this will help you

Comment: But I have one doubt that when I remove this transform property then also it works fine.And I also checked that in any case this property is same.Can you please tell me this ?

Comment: And what if I removed this property from grid, will it imact anything in functionality?
Bcoz this is not documented anywhere on their site.

Comment: This css property implementing by inbuilt class or ExtJS library. You need to debug the inbuilt class for grid. You can simply remove by using overriding class. But I don't think you need to do this.

Comment: For more details you can refer this class [Table.js](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/api/src/Table.js-2.html)  or [Ext.view.Table](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/api/Ext.view.Table.html)